# 'Entry' object has no attribute 'topic' problem in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working with Django and I'm stuck in editing entries in views app because of this error:

> 'Entry' object has no attribute 'topic'

Code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id) 
    topic = entry.topic
    
    if request != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)  
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)   
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)
    context = { 'entry':entry, 'topic':topic, 'form':form }   
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

It says the problem is from line: **topic = entry.topic** but I can't figure it out.

class Entry(models.ModelForm) declaration:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    topic_id = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
    
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```

Comment: Well it looks like there is no `.topic` for entry. Can you share the `Entry` model?

Comment: You have to share ```Entry``` model code.

Comment: How can I share it?

Comment: Edit your question and add the part of your code where you declare `class Entry(models.Model)`

Comment: I edited it and appreciate it if you take a look at it, @quqa123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Entry` object doesn't have `topic` attribute - it has `topic_id` attribute so in order to get what I suppose you want you should change

```
topic = entry.topic
```

to

```
topic = entry.topic_id
```

and you should be good to go. I might suspect that you are beginning your Django journey and got confused with the `ForeignKey` attribute naming. It's pointless to name it `topic_id` in class based programming as conceptually in Django you don't store there the sole `id` instead you have some kind of reference to the `Topic` instance so by intuition your `topic_id` attribute should be named just `topic`